# Angular 4 throw specific error

Tags: angular

In my angular 4 project I want to throw an error with a specific code like:

```
throw 50
```

then in my custom globar error handler I want to catch this specific number error.

In my **component.ts** I make a call to get the data.

```
loadModelData( event: LazyLoadEvent ) {
this.loader = true;
this.userService.getUsers( event, this.searchString )
.subscribe( response => {
this.totalElements = response.page.totalElements;
this.userList = response._embedded.users as User[];
this.loader = false;
} );
}
```

In the **service** I make the get call but I have to check some boolean before to make it and throw exception.

```
getUsers(event: LazyLoadEvent, search: string) {
// TODO check controller
if (true) { throw 50
// return this.http.get(url + '?' + this.setEventParams(event, search))
.map((response: Response) => <any>response);
    }
  }
```

If I throw this error in the console I have:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): 50
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881) [angular]
>       at timer (zone.js:1732) []

How can catch it in my custom error handler?
Alternatively can I throw others specific error?

Comment: Have you tried before asking? I don't see why it wouldn't work. Don't expect the application to continue normally after an uncaught exception though.

Comment: Yes, in my handler I can't do `if (error === 50) {
    console.log('error 50')}` How can I recognize it in in my handler

Comment: what do you get in your handler if you remove the `if` and just add `console.log('error: ', error);`?

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): 50
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881) [angular]
    at timer (zone.js:1732) [<root>]

Comment: So this means the error is thrown inside async code. You could try `if(error instanceof Promise) { error.then((err) => console.log('async error: ', error); } else { console.log('error: ', error); }`. If the error is thrown inside observable callbacks, it might look even different (haven't tried).

Comment: It don't print async error,

Comment: My code has a mistake. `(err) => console.log('async error: ', err /* or - should be removed*/);`. So what did it print?

Comment: no it prints the else block: `error:  Error: Uncaught (in promise): 50
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881) [angular]
    at timer (zone.js:1732) [<root>]`

Comment: If you can reproduce in a Plunker I'd have a closer look. Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular 4 template. Just click "new > Angular"

Comment: I bit long to reproduce in a plunker, i'll try

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am not very familiar with plunker, I updated my question

Comment: Plunker is really simple. With "new" you get a selection of templates, chose Angular. Add files as needed ("New file"). Doubleclick files to rename them, add `/` to the file name  (`src/filename.ts`) to move them into directories. You only need to add your error handler service source, add it as provider to the module and add the code that throws the exception similar to how it happens in your local project.

Comment: in the plunker I have `ERROR Error: 50
    at UserService.getUsers` and not the promise...

Comment: That's probably because in your project `getUsers()` or `loadModelData()` is called from some async code.

Comment: So how can I catch it, or maybe can you tell me another way to throw an error in this case?

Comment: You could try an observable like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46096664/217408
and throw inside `subscribe` and check if this reproduces your local behavior

Comment: Now in the console I see: ERROR 50

Comment: In the Plunker or in your local project? With what code? Can you please post the Plunker link?

Comment: In the local project

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: throwing the error in the subscribe    `const sub = Observable.interval(1000)
      .subscribe((val) => {throw 50})`

Comment: But that is artificial code. You want that behavior in your original code, don't you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153877/discussion-between-alessandro-and-gunter-zochbauer).