# Call a function every 10 seconds Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to create a `Timer` that calls an `API call` every 10 seconds, I'm using `setTimeOut` but the thing is that it becomes an infinite loop, and even if I push to another page it keeps joining the if condition.

Example :

I call this on a method to start the 10 seconds API calls

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.onTimeOut();
}, 1000);
```

And this is the `onTimeOut()` method...

```
onTimeOut() {
    this.ApiCall().then(
    success => {
    if(success ['ok'] == 0){
        this.navCtrl.push(myPage);
    }
    },
    error => { console.log(error); });
}
setTimeout(() => {
    this.onTimeOut();
}, 1000);
}
```

I've heard about `Debounce` and `rxjs/rs` but I'm not familiar with them, could you give me some tips to do the same with that? Or if this way is more efficient go ahead and explain to me why it becomes to a loop.

The goal is when it joins the if and push the page, stop the timer.

Comment: You say "10 seconds" but pass `}, 1000);` to `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Better use observables

```
this.sub = Observable.interval(10000)
    .subscribe((val) => { console.log('called'); });
```

to stop it use

```
this.sub.unsubscribe();
```

Make sure to import `interval` with

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
```

Comment: What is "this.sub"?

Comment: A class-level field`sub:Subscription;`

Comment: Do I have to import something?

Comment: Everything, as always. `Observable`, `Subscription` if you type it. I don't know the imports by heart, but there is a question with an answer to every one already ;-)

Comment: I'm gonna test your answer, so... I have to put inside of .subscrive((val) the api call, right? And then after or before the push unsuscribe? By the way what is val? what value is? I know there are lot of questions, but it's about the same stuff... I can't create n questions, I guess they are quiet simple to reply :P

Comment: Unsubscribe is only when you want it to stop calling your code every 10sec. Perhaps you could explain in more detail what behavior your expect exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153874/discussion-between-stuart2041-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: hi gunter, is it a complete code because when i type this.sub = Observable.interval(10000)
      .subscribe((val) => {
        console.log('called');
      }   --> i get an error --> ',' expected (i.e. a comma expected)

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava sorry, no idea where this error comes from.

Comment: interval is blocking the page load :/

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I doubt that. Your problem is most likely something else.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this.fetchTick();this.tick = interval(20000).subscribe((time) => {this.fetchTick();}) this is the code i run in ngOnInit.. and page wait till 20 secs and when i remove tick..it load instantly

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you check the code i provided? I am still unable to make that work...Angular universal cli one i am using

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer have u checked?

Comment: `import { interval } from 'rxjs';` would work with the latest versions of Angular, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074485/angular2-rxjs-missing-observable-interval-method

Comment: updated `this.sub = interval(10000).subscribe((val) => { console.log('called'); });`

Answer (score 36):

from **RxJS 6+** you just use interval.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

//in 10 seconds do something
interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
    this.myFunctionThatDoesStuff();
});
```

you can use `Subscription` with the interval.

```
import { interval, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
export class intervalDemo{
    mySubscription: Subscription

    constructor(){
    this.mySubscription= interval(5000).subscribe((x =>{
                this.doStuff();
            }));
    }
    doStuff(){
        //doing stuff with unsubscribe at end to only run once
        this.failedRequestSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: When i use this. first it waits for 5 secs then only it does the stuff. How to do the stuffs then wait for 5 seconds?

Comment: Simple way is to call the function just before you start the interval.

Comment: Remember to remove the interval after it's completed as well. If you only unsubscribe the subscription the interval will still keep running. I prefer using `takeUntil`, for example: `this. mySubscription = interval(5000).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(() => { doStuff(); })` and remove it: `ngOnDestroy() { this.destroy$.next(); this.destroy$.complete(); }`

Answer (score 11):

A better solution than setTimeout in an Angular app could be to use Observable. Observable have a method named timer that you can use this way (and there is a TimerObservable too but I never used it so I don't know if this is the same thing):

```
timer = Observable.timer(initialDelay, period);

timer.subscribe(tick => {
   // Your API call, which will be performed every period
});
```

I encourage you to use RxJS and Observable for your requests too, instead of promises, it seams more the Angular way to do things to me, and RxJS is a really powerful library.

[RxJS Observable doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html)

Comment: I like this but what if the api happens to be slow sometimes?
Is it possible, as an extension to this, call the api at every tick, except in the case where the previous call has not completed? If the previous call has not completed, the next call should be scheduled to as soon as the previous finishes.

Comment: As HTTP calls are asynchronous it could be difficult to do such things.

You could try to play with callbacks and Observable like that: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mrv4rLbd/

Comment: You could use the `debounce` operator: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounce.

I didn't tried but storing the last API call and debounce on it may work.

Answer (score 3):

Use `observable.timer` for your purpose in angular way.

```
 export class CurrentRunsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private timer;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.timer = Observable.timer(10000);
    this.timer.subscribe((t) => this.onTimeOut());
  }
   onTimeOut() {
    this.ApiCall().then(
    success => {
    if(success ['ok'] == 0){
        this.navCtrl.push(myPage);
    }
    },
    error => { console.log(error); });
}

   ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log("Destroy timer");

  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning timer which doesn't do the initial delay. Import import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer'; instead

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with setTiimeout, It’s just a bug in your codes. This is indeed an infinite loop(recursive function without a base condition) as you don't have any base condition there.

**So, setTimeout will keep on calling onTimeOut() after every 1 second as it does not know where to stop. Just use a base condition to finish the recursion when you switch to other pages.**

```
 private flag: boolean;

 ngOnInit() {
        this.flag = true;
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
        this.flag = false;
 }
 onTimeOut() {
        this.ApiCall().then(
        success => {
        if(success ['ok'] == 0){
            this.navCtrl.push(myPage);
        }
        },
        error => { console.log(error); });
    }
     setTimeout(() => {
     if(this.flag){
        this.onTimeOut();
     }
    }, 1000);
    }
```

`ngOnDestroy` method will set the flag as false and the last call of the recursive function won't go inside the if block and as there is nothing to be executed after that, It will return back (previous state of it) and will clear it up from the stack, This process will be repeated till the stack is cleared up(same thing would happen to previous version of it which is now on the top of the stack and thus will clear up the stack one by one recursively).