# Consuming a rest api every 5s

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, ionic-framework, spring-rest

i wanna call my rest-service(SpringBoot) with a TypeScript code evrey 5s to give me the newest Information, i wrote this code i'm getting the information but 
i did'nt know how to let him do it evrey 5s !!! Any One Can helps me

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController, PopoverController} from "ionic-angular";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
url:string;
data1:any;
ticket:aiticket[];
result:any=[];
PDV1:any;


  constructor(public nav: NavController, public http: HttpClient,public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {
}
getdata(){
  var url='http://localhost:8282/6733/notif';
console.log("Clickeed");
this.data1 = this.http.get(url);
this.data1.subscribe(data1 => {
this.result = data1;
for(let key of data1){
  console.log(key.pdv)
  console.log(key.data[0]);
this.PDV1=key.data[0]; //i'm using this to call it in the HTML page
}
});}

}
```

Comment: not a good solution but your can wrap your function inside `setTimeout()`

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096587/call-a-function-every-10-seconds-angular2?noredirect=1&lq=1