# best place to make continuous api call in angular throughout the application

Tags: angular, api

I have a requirement where I have to make a api call every minute irrespective of current page, i.e throughout the app (Angular 7 app).
what is best place to call this api (App component or anywhere better place), so that I din't make any design mistake.
your suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: It can anywhere but I would go with app.component + [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096587/call-a-function-every-10-seconds-angular2/46096664#46096664)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it in a `Service` which would be created and used by the `AppComponent`.

It's recommended that `HttpClient` calls are wrapped within services instead of being used in Components directly. This allows for greater flexibility for your application structure as you can reuse your your calls throughout the app, as well the ability to implement more advanced features such as caching.

And the timer would be in the `AppComponent`, not in the Service.