# How to auto refresh page in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to reload my page automatically(auto postback to reload table data) if my page is open. For that I have written some code but that is not working. See my code below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable,Subscription, interval  } from 'rxjs';

export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  private updateSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.updateSubscription = interval(3000).subscribe(
     (val) => { this.getProducts()});

    });
  }

  private getProducts()
  {
    this.employeeService.getProducts().subscribe((data:any) => {
      console.log(data);
     this.products=data;});

  }

}
```

`getProducts` calling rest Api. How can I got it working?

Comment: What's 'load a page'?

Comment: What do you mean with "load my page automatically"? What exactly do you want to load automatically? Your current implementation starts a subscription that will call `this.getProducts()` once every second.

Comment: @Ivan - Auto reload means automatic postback on page if someone keep open my website.

Comment: @Scorpioo590 - I want to get product latest status of products and bind to table. For rhat I need to automatic refresh my page if page is open.

Comment: So you don' want to refresh your page but load data from an external source every one second?

Comment: Yeah I want to load refresh and any product failed so execute that again. Not every one seconds like every 30sec or 1min.

Comment: I would suggest not to call API for every second, this will hit server every second (that's a bad practice), instead give user a **button to refresh** or use **web socket**

Comment: @SameerKhan - Every one min I want to reload table data.

Comment: @SameerKhan I'd agree but would argue that for a small user base a periodic pull might be sufficient.

Can you post your `this.getProducts()` method? And can you verify that it actually gets called?

Comment: At first sight this looks good. Does the `console.log` get called? Can you confirm via Developer Tools that the request is actually sent?

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya `this.updateSubscription = interval(60000).subscribe((val) => this.getProducts());` - function **this.getProducts()** will invoke for every one minute

Comment: @Scorpioo590 - Yeah its working when checked from inspect element. Thansks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given code in question working for me. Initially I was waiting page to reload. But when I put debug point in inspected element every interval my code was executing.

```
import { Observable,Subscription, interval  } from 'rxjs';
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  private updateSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.updateSubscription = interval(3000).subscribe(
     (val) => { this.getProducts()});

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import { Observable, interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class YourComponent ... {

  private updateSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.updateSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(
        (val) => { this.updateStats()
      }

  );
}
```

Comment: This is the angular-valid syntax of defining a component. I guess that @ArvindChourasiya left this out only for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @Scorpioo590 - I have do have components and all. Just I have posted optimal code. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If the reload is only important for you and not your users, you can just use

```
ng serve --poll=2000
```

This way your project will be updated every time you change something in your code or every 2 seconds. But it won't update if completely nothing changes, I think he recognizes that pretty well.

Comment: This will reload the page if the resources change. This is the default behaviour of `ng serve` and does not address OP's problem that he wants to reload something from a remote server every n seconds.

Comment: By the way, after switching to Windows 10, ng serve doesn't automatically update the resources anymore. But thank you for pointing out

Comment: That's weird. I'm using Windows 10 as well and `ng serve` is working as expected. Which version of the cli are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call in the component constructor.

```
 constructor(){

       Observable.interval(1000)
        .subscribe((val) => { console.log('called'); 
    this.getProducts();
    });
    }
```

[Also see this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096587/call-a-function-every-10-seconds-angular2)

Comment: Can you elaborate why this should be an answer? What would be the difference between putting it in the constructor vs. putting it in the onInit method?

Comment: @Scorpioo590. I did not say this is the answer. I said try this because if (Arvind Chourasiya) code is not working in init() method then try to put in the constructor(). but try to use Observable

Comment: If it is not an answer then please do not provide it as one.
There is no reason to belive that anything that does not work in the onInit method would work in the constructor.
Furthermore AFAIK there is no `interval` method on `Observable`

Comment: @Scorpioo590. This is a working example I have tried in my system and right now I cannot reply in the comment section because my reputation did not reach 50. Also, if Arvind Chourasiya tries this. It may help because it is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Check your brackets and parentheses. They are wrong.

Should be:

````
import { Observable,Subscription, interval  } from 'rxjs';

export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  private updateSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.updateSubscription = interval(3000).subscribe(
     (val) => { this.getProducts()});
  }

  private getProducts()
  {
    this.employeeService.getProducts().subscribe((data:any) => {
      console.log(data);
     this.products=data;});

  }

}```
````