# How to auto refresh page/component view in angular

Tags: angular

I have a dashboard page which displays around ten tables. Each table is a separate component and fetches data using it's on API. I have a requirement to auto refresh this page every five minutes (let's say). I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateSubscription = interval(120000).subscribe(() => {
      this.getDataByName();
    });
  }

  public getDataByName(): void {
    this.httpMarketData.getTableByType('Customer Table').subscribe((response: TableData[]) => {
      this.getTableData(response);
    });
  }
```

I referred it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60148181/how-to-auto-refresh-page-in-angular). But it doesn't work and I stop seeing any data. Any suggestions how to achieve it? I was thinking to call these APIs from each component to auto refresh themselves in a similar way.

Comment: first data will be fetched after your set delay, i think you want to use timer(0, 5000) instead of interval(5000)

Comment: @enno.void Thanks a bunch mate. That seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateSubscription = timer(0, 120000).pipe(
      switchMap(x => this.httpMarketData.getTableByType('Customer Table'))
    ).subscribe((response: TableData[]) => {
      this.getTableData(response);
    });
}
```

Explanation:

1. Use `timer` instead of `interval`
2. Use `switchMap` to switch to the http-observable after every delay.

Comment: Do we need `updateSubscription` ? Also, can I move this piece of code in the method itself than `ngOnInit` block? Would I then need to call `ngOnInit` from this one to update the view? I see data coming now at regular interval but view isn't getting updated.

Comment: 1.Yes you need it. You have to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy, otherwise it will produce a memoryleak because the timer runs for an infinte amount of time, even if the table-component is destroyed.

2. I think ngOnInit is a good place.

3. "but view isn't getting updated" this seems to be an problem of `this.getTableData(response)` if the requests are fired properly

Comment: `this.getTableData(response)` is actually an `input` to the parent component selector, does that mean rather than input, should be like an event or something? I believe the input change isn't getting transmitted to the parent properly on the refreshes?

Comment: Dont really get your last comment, so i created this example - hope it helps:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-np9vky?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the help!! In my last comment I was trying to say that this data is an array and it works as an input to another component. Now it displays properly for the first time but next time when this data array changes, I think angular doesn't detect it. Just a guess. Thanks for all the help again!!